# Edge offset evenly spaced around an asymmetrical object?

Tags: scale

Given a rectangle with a subdivided mesh, if I edge select around the rectangle and scale outward (on the X/Y in this case) it will not scale the edges evenly. The distance from the rectangle to the final landing space is uneven (see screenshot).

**How do I scale an asymmetrical object evenly, so that the sides are equidistant to the origin?**

*Note, I extruded the selection first so you can see the uneven sides more easily post X/Y scale.*

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're creating a non-manifold mesh, as illustrated, you can use the shipped add-on *Edit Mesh Tools > Edge Tools > Offset* with the *Extrude* option.

[image]

Less long-winded if you are extruding a face-ring.. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Along Normals*, with *Offset Even* checked.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, the edges are still not evenly extruded with this suggestion.

Comment: @work-ed .. I always try stuff out before posting... are you sure your object isn't carrying an object-level scale transform? (Was it scaled in Object Mode?)

Comment: Yep, that was it. Object level scale not applied. Thanks for your help and comments, much appreciated.